# Dynamically set filterset_class in Django ListView

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a ListView where I would like to set a different filterset for each user: if the user is in group admin it would have a specific Filterset; if it is a standard user another Filterset will be applied. How can I do this? In the documentation they say that I can override the method get_filterset_class() when I am using DjangoRestFramework but I am not using it.

```
class StandardFilterset(FilterSet):

    field_1 = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Model.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StandardFilterset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['field_1'].extra.update({ 'widget': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'text'}) })

    class Meta:

        model = Model
        fields = {
            'field_1': ['exact'],
        }


class AdminFilterSet(FilterSet):

    field_1 = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Model.objects.all())
    active = django_filters.BooleanFilter(label='Is active', field_name='active')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdminFilterSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['field_1'].extra.update({ 'widget': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'text'}) })
        self.filters['active'].extra.update({ 'widget': django_filters.widgets.BooleanWidget(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'text'}) })

    class Meta:

        model = Model
        fields = {
            'field_1': ['exact'],
            'active': ['exact'],
        }

class AListView(GroupRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    group_required = [ "Standard", "Administrator",]
    filterset_class = StandardFilterset
    template_name = 'temp/a_listview.html'
    context_object_name = 'a'
```

In "AListView" filterset_class is set to StandardFilterset and the other filterset "AdminFilterSet" is different (here it has a field more). How can I change filterset in AListView based on the user stored in the request? Is there a method similar to get_filterset_class() used in DRF?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset` method of the `ListView`, and change the default `filterset_class` if the user belongs to the *Administrator* group. It would be something like this:

```py
class AListView(GroupRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    # Specify a model or a queryset
    model = YourModel
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    group_required = [ "Standard", "Administrator",]
    filterset_class = StandardFilterset
    template_name = 'temp/a_listview.html'
    context_object_name = 'a'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Administrator').exists():
            self.filterset_class = AdminFilterSet
        self.filter = self.filterset_class(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return self.filter.qs
```

I always use [this](http://ccbv.co.uk/) website to check the attributes and methods of Django's Class-Based Views to know what I can override when I need something to be done differently.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. The variable self.filter is called self.filterset, maybe because I am still using Django 1.11